# Comparing ActiveRecord objects with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

Is there a good way in Rspec to compare two ActiveRecord objects while ignoring id, &c? For example, say I'm parsing one object from XML and loading the other from a fixture, and what I'm testing is that my XML parser works correctly. What I currently have is a custom matcher with

```
actual.attributes.reject{|key,v| %w"id updated_at created_at".include? key } == expected.attributes.reject{|key,v| %w"id updated_at created_at".include? key }
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way.

And then slightly more complicated, but is there a way to do a similar thing on a *set*? Say said XML parser also creates several objects that belong_to the original object. So the set I'm ending up with should be identical except for id, created_at, &c, and I'm wondering if there's a good way to test that beyond just cycling through, clearing out those variables, and checking.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A shorter way to write the above would be `actual.attributes.except(:id, :updated_at, :created_at)`.

If you are using this a lot, you can always define your own matcher like this:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_same_attributes_as do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    ignored = [:id, :updated_at, :created_at]
    actual.attributes.except(*ignored) == expected.attributes.except(*ignored)
  end
end
```

Put this into your `spec_helper.rb` you can now say in any example:

```
User.first.should have_same_attributes_as(User.last)
```

Good luck.

Comment: for me it works only with quotes `["id", "updated_at", "created_at"]`

Comment: To make it working both with strings and symbols, you can use HashWithIndifferentAccess: `actual.attributes.with_indifferent_access.except...`.

Comment: I get `undefined method `attributes'` when I try this. What can be wrong?