# RSpec fails when matching two classes, even though the classes are _identical_

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, pandastream

I have the following piece of code that checks if the returned video object is the same as the one I put in.

The video object is a [Panda Stream](http://www.pandastream.com/docs/integrate_with_rails) object, and referring to their homepage, the `Panda::Video.find` should return *exactly* the object I put in with the `Panda::Video.create` method.

```
# screencast_spec.rb
before(:each) do
  @screencast = Factory.build(:screencast)
  @video = Panda::Video.create(:source_url => "http://panda-test-harness-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/panda.mp4")
end
it "should fetch the video with the #video method" do
  @screencast.video = @video
  @screencast.video.should == @video
end

# screencast.rb
# Returns the panda::video object
def video
  Panda::Video.find(self.video_id)
end
# Sets the +video_id+ reference
def video= video_object_or_id
  video_object_or_id = video_object_or_id.id unless video_object_or_id.is_a?(Integer)
  self.video_id = video_object_or_id
end
```

The error that RSpec returns is this:

```
1) Screencast#video should fetch the video with the #video method
Failure/Error: @screencast.video.should == @video
   expected: #<Panda::Video id: "dac9bf057c9b667f57096054a64625a1", created_at: "2012/01/29 18:04:07 +0000", updated_at: "2012/01/29 18:04:07 +0000", original_filename: "panda.mp4", source_url: "http://panda-test-harness-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/panda.mp4", duration: nil, height: nil, width: nil, extname: ".mp4", file_size: nil, video_bitrate: nil, audio_bitrate: nil, audio_codec: nil, video_codec: nil, fps: nil, audio_channels: nil, audio_sample_rate: nil, status: "processing", path: "dac9bf057c9b667f57096054a64625a1", cloud_id: "55372b1612963b045f27bb093fed0abb">
        got: #<Panda::Video id: "dac9bf057c9b667f57096054a64625a1", created_at: "2012/01/29 18:04:07 +0000", updated_at: "2012/01/29 18:04:07 +0000", original_filename: "panda.mp4", source_url: "http://panda-test-harness-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/panda.mp4", duration: nil, height: nil, width: nil, extname: ".mp4", file_size: nil, video_bitrate: nil, audio_bitrate: nil, audio_codec: nil, video_codec: nil, fps: nil, audio_channels: nil, audio_sample_rate: nil, status: "processing", path: "dac9bf057c9b667f57096054a64625a1", cloud_id: "55372b1612963b045f27bb093fed0abb"> (using ==)
   Diff:
 # ./spec/models/screencast_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Note the diff saying that there is *no* difference between the two objects, so why is the comparison failing?

If any of you have any pointers, or have tried testing the [panda stream](http://www.pandastream.com/docs/integrate_with_rails) before I would appreciate all the guidance I can get

Comment: here is the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763983/comparing-activerecord-objects-with-rspec

Comment: But shouldn't the objects be exactly alike, not only sharing attribute likeness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ruby provides 3 methods for testing for equality `==` `eql?` `equals?`. when using `==` you are comparing by object identity. ruby uses the object-id for this. the important thing is that classes can redefine `==` like it's done for string-comparison.

if you wan't to learn more on this topic i can advise you this blog post: http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/ruby-equality-and-object-comparison/