# Overriding ActiveRecord::Base == operator - good idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I am having problems with Rspec and ActiveRecord::Base. I want to check if my parser creates model instances correctly.

I tried comparing new objects to new objects, but found out it won't work. Then I tried saving the objects, but that's also really not a solution - because if I create expected model instances too, then the ids will differ.

I resorted to overriding the == operator to match all my fields, without the id. I feel this is an icky solution though.

What is the correct way to tackle this problem?

Comment: My hunch is that a ton of things internal to ActiveRecord would catastrophically break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I think it's a bad idea.  How would you go about testing pure equality?

I would write (or find via google) an rspec matcher called say "matches_attributes" that would compare each objects attribute list and if they were identical return true.

Comment: It seems like such a matcher is indeed the way to go. Found this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763983/comparing-activerecord-objects-with-rspec) and its answer proved to be helpful. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @Lasooch That is exactly what you want!  Sweet.